# How to enforce a Oracle DB to only allow insertion of ASCII chars in any table within it?

Tags: sql, oracle, ascii

I have several tables in Oracle DB, they will have the columns with usual data, which can be strings, numbers, time/date etc. The only restriction here is that, whenever inserting new data, it should throw an error if it's not ASCII.

Is there such an attribute/property in Oracle that could guarantee me that I am dealing with only ASCII?

Comment: I was going to answer: "Create a database with the US7ASCII character set" but apparently that character set is no longer available in 11G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a check constraint for that:

```
alter table foo 
  add constraint check_ascii 
  check (asciistr(the_column) = the_column);
```

asciistr() will "escape" all non-ASCII characters. So if the result of that function is different to the input it contains non-ascii characters.